# Android Studio Emulator View Issue

Tags: java, android, mobile

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4kHa.png)Hello,
I downloaded Andorid Studio 2022 and ran the emulator. There is no problem until here, but the emulator works as in the picture. I want the phone itself to come directly. How can I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways for windows and mac :

For Windows :

Go to File -> Settings -> Tools -> Emulator and then turn off Launch in a tool window option.

For Mac :

Go to Android Studio Menu -> Preferences -> Tools -> Emulator and then turn off Launch in a tool window option.

Comment: My problem is solved. Thank you very much.

Comment: Kindly upvote as well so that it can help others as well. @ErenAkgöz